# Getting duplicate records while using update strategy transformation

Tags: informatica

Am trying to upload an oracle target table from a flat file and based on some matching conditions with other table (using lookup transformation). Before loading the target table we have a router transformation where it has 2 group conditions - one for update and other for insert.The column values from the update group is being routed to update strategy which again routed to target to load the data. Here the values are not getting updated with newer records instead it's inserting as a new record. We have declared 2 columns as composite primary keys. Can we give the conditions in any of the transformation level before loading it in the target instead of target override option?

Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: "Here the values are not getting updated with newer records instead it's inserting as a new record." - This will happen if it matches the condition in the insert path. "We have declared 2 columns as composite primary keys. Can we give the conditions in any of the transformation level before loading it in the target instead of target override option?" Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: When we use the update strategy transformation(here using DD_UPDATE flag) it'll update only the key columns and if we want to update the non key columns we need to use the update override option in target definition correct? if i use the query override option in target ,will the changes be applied before loading into the  target?

Comment: DD_UPDATE sets the row to update and the key column acts as the "where clause" in the update statement. I assume you want to update for non key column. A better way of doing it is to create a duplicate target definition in the designer with the non-key as the primary key and use it.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Already i have a separate target definition for update statement. Here am trying to overwrite with update overwrite option in target definition. For that i have copied the same mapping with diff name and session task in the folder. But when i tried to update  with new mapping name it wont allow me to do it.

Comment: Now am able to edit the mapping name by exporting as xml file.If i use update override in target definition, will the changes be applied after of before loading into the table?Also can i refer other tables for matching conditions in that query?

Answer (score 0):

When you override the update query then it becomes the load into the table. So before or after doesn't apply here. You can refer other tables provided all other rules and guidelines for override are met.